# What was the League of Sublime and Perfect Masters?

Tags: europe, 19th-century, italy, french-revolution

What was the League of the Sublime and Perfect Masters, created when the Congress of Viena was  finished?  What role did it play in Italian Reunification?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The League of the Sublime and Perfect Masters (Sublime Perfect Masters / Society of Perfect Sublime Masters) was a conspiratorial and revolutionary society, one of the [Carbonari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonari) groups. It was created in 1818 by [Filippo  Buonarroti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Buonarroti) and it operated as a Masonic Lodge. Its headquarters were in Turin and its immediate goal was independence from Austria. Its long terms goals were probably those of its founder; the creation of a communist society.

Buonarroti used the society to direct and manipulate sectarian activities all over Italy, however due to the secretive nature and structure of the society very little direct evidence of its operations exist.

Sources:

- [A History of Italy, 1700-1860: The Social Constraints of Political Change](http://books.google.gr/books?id=yZ8OAAAAQAAJ), Stuart Joseph Woolf
- [The Good Cousins' Domain of Belonging: Tropes in Southern Italian Secret Society Symbol and Ritual, 1810-1821](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3033969), Anthony H. Galt
- [Pius IX](http://books.google.gr/books?id=Jeie3FBTC1sC), Roberto De Mattei
- [The unification of Italy](http://books.google.gr/books?id=oFPI8gWmzyAC), John Gooch.